# Creating Chessboard with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a chessboard with Javascript. I already managed to create the board itself, but I'm having trouble giving every field its fitting class (black or white).

I managed to correctly assign the classes for the first row, but am having trouble with the rest of the board. I know there are probably easier solutions to this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chess</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/chess.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="initGame()">
<h1>Chess</h1>
<div id="board">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/chess.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
body{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
}
#board{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: white;
}
#board div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.white{
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.black{
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```
const board = [];
const boardElement = document.getElementById("board");


function initGame(){
    for(var y = 0; y < 8; y++){
        var row = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < 8; x++){
            var cell = {};
            cell.element = document.createElement("div")
            boardElement.appendChild(cell.element);
            row.push(cell);
        }
        board.push(row);
    }
    $("#board div").addClass("field white");
    for(var i = 0; i < board.length * 8; i++){
        if((i % 7) == 0 && i != 0){
            $(".field")[i].className = "field black";
            i++;
        }
        else if((i % 7) == 0){
            i++;
        }
        $(".field")[i].className = "field black";
        i++;
    }
    startGame();
}
function startGame(){

}
```

The current output: [image]

Comment: You could accomplish the black/white with css using nth-child.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought that assigning classes would make it easier to actually move the chess pieces and determine the possible moves for each piece.

Comment: Altering the loop counter variable `i` conditionally makes for a very confusing algorithm. What was your idea?

Comment: at first, I wanted to make every second field black, but then I realized that it switches every round and tried to find an easy workaround.

Comment: Your logic for moving pieces should not depend on any CSS, only on coordinates. So go with `nth-child` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53748510/5459839)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cut down your initGame logic to just add white class when y and x are either both odd or both even. You can do this by `y%2 == x%2`. You won't need the extra for loop.!

```
function initGame(){
    for(var y = 0; y < 8; y++){
        var row = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < 8; x++){
            var cell = {};
            cell.element = document.createElement("div")
            if(y%2 ==  x%2)
            {
                cell.element.className = "field white";
            }
            else 
            {
                cell.element.className = "field black";
            }
            boardElement.appendChild(cell.element);
            row.push(cell);
        }
        board.push(row);
    }

    startGame();
}
```

Comment: `y%2 == x%2` nice!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what other functionality you'd need, but for generating the board you could do something like this:

```js
const md = () => document.createElement('div');

function makeBoard (container, length = 8) {
 for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   const row = md();
  Array.from({length}).forEach(() => row.appendChild(md()));
    container.appendChild(row);
  }
}

makeBoard(document.getElementById('board'));
```

```css
#board > div {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 32px;
}

#board > div > div {
  flex: 0 0 32px;
  background: tomato;
}

#board > div:nth-child(even) > div:nth-child(even) {
  background: bisque;
}

#board > div:nth-child(odd) > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: bisque;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with swapping array:

```
var colors = ['white', 'black'];

$("#board div").each(function(i) {
  if((i % 2) == 0)
    $(this).addClass(colors[0]);
  else 
    $(this).addClass(colors[1]);
  if([8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64].indexOf((i + 1)) > -1)
    colors = colors.reverse();
});
```

```js
const board = [];
const boardElement = document.getElementById("board");


function initGame(){
    for(var y = 0; y < 8; y++){
        var row = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < 8; x++){
            var cell = {};
            cell.element = document.createElement("div")
            boardElement.appendChild(cell.element);
            row.push(cell);
        }
        board.push(row);
    }
    
    $("#board div").addClass('field');
    
    var colors = ['white', 'black'];
    
    $("#board div").each(function(i) {
      if((i % 2) == 0)
        $(this).addClass(colors[0]);
      else 
        $(this).addClass(colors[1]);
      if([8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64].indexOf((i + 1)) > -1)
        colors = colors.reverse();
    });
    
    // startGame();
}
```

```css
body{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
}
#board{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
}
#board div{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.white{
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.black{
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chess</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/chess.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="initGame()">
<h1>Chess</h1>
<div id="board">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/chess.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```